# Slick: how to return an error on update if zero row was updated

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I want to return an error if I try to update an inexistant row in Slick.

my query:

```
userPromotions.filter(promo =>
  promo.code === code).update(myUpdatedRow)
```

the query I try to do (I have an error cause "rowToUpdate.exist" is a Rep[Boolean] and not a Boolean):

```
val rowToUpdate = userPromotions.filter(promo => promo.code === code)
if(rowToUpdate.exist) rowToUpdate.update(myUpdatedRow)
else NotFound
```

is there any way to do that in a single query ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Slick 3.0 and above

Using `DBIO.failed` you can fail the transaction when number of updated rows is 0

```
userPromotions.filter(_.code === code).update(myUpdatedRow).flatMap { updatedRows =>
  if (updatedRows == 0) DBIO.failed(new Exception("0 rows updated"))
  else DBIO.successful(updatedRows)
}.transactionally
```